# Jenkins' GitHub access suddenly stop working

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

We are using Jenkins version 2.10 on Windows Server 2012 to build a project in a private GitHub repository.

**Everything has been working fine for months, until suddenly automatic Jenkins builds stopped working, seemingly out of the blue.**

I am not the one who installed and set this system up so I'm not entirely knownledgable how it is configured.

We are using Jenkins's Git plugin to give Jenkins access to our private repository. The Git plugin is configured with the HTTPS URL of our private repo and the private SSH key directly typed in Jenkins. The public key is correctly set on GitHub.

Here is the Git Polling Log showing the symptoms:

```
Started on Jun 27, 2016 11:30:07 AM
Polling SCM changes on master
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision f8ec9ba340db92754ba2ee5b5e8ac8a6d719c5ec (origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/XXX/YYY.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/XXX/YYY.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.username EcosystemBuilder # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\builder\AppData\Local\Temp\git1306578611748988291.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/XXX/YYY.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This last command hangs until it times out (after 10 minutes). Looking at Process Explorer:

[image: Processes spawned by Jenkins]

It looks like `git-credential-manager.exe` is spawned with a single `get` command line argument, and is thus popping up a window (which we don't see) asking for a user name and a password.

From the Git Polling Log above, one can see the following line:

```
git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\builder\AppData\Local\Temp\git1306578611748988291.credentials\"
```

Here is the entire content of the file `git1306578611748988291.credentials`:

```
https://github.com
```

whereas I expect it to contain some kind of credentials allowing Git to access our private repo.

As far as I know, nothing has changed in the Jenkins configuration, nor on the machine.

Jenkins plugins versions:

- git 2.5.0
- git-client 1.19.6
- git-server 1.6
- github 1.19.2
- github-api 1.75
- ssh-credentials 1.12

**At this point I would appreciate any input that would allow to refine my understanding of the problem and/or post a more precise question.**

Answer (score 0):

git-credential-manager.exe is in newly version
ex:Git-2.9.3.2-64-bit no ok

I rollback to:Git-2.5.0-64-bit,it's ok  and not exist git-credential-manager.exe